# Nested relationship ACF field not calling correct content

Tags: wordpress, modal-dialog, relationship, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I have a repeater field for various properties. Inside that repeater field, I have a relationship subfield for references. When the "Open Modal" button is clicked, a modal pops up and should display the associated references for that property. Everything works except for the fact that no matter which property you click, it's only displaying the references for the first property. I have tried repositioning the endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); but have not been able to fix this issue.

Here is [the link](http://apidatabase.wpengine.com/?api=levonorgestrel) to the page.

Below is my PHP code:

```
<?php if( have_rows('api_properties') ): ?>
            <ul>
            <?php while ( have_rows('api_properties') ) : the_row(); ?>

                <li>

                <?php 

                    $name = get_sub_field('api_name'); 
                    $value = get_sub_field('api_value');
                    $posts = get_sub_field('api_references');
                ?>                          
                    <div class="w3-container">

                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                    <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Open Modal</button>
                    <p><?php echo $name; ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $value; ?></p>

                    <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
                        <div class="w3-modal-content">
                          <header class="w3-container w3-teal"> 
                            <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" 
                            class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
                            <h2>References</h2>
                            </header>

                        <div class="w3-container">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="header"><span>Title</span><span>Description</span><span class="number">Ref #</span><span>PDF</span></li>
                        </ul>
                        <?php if( $posts ): ?>
                                    <ul>
                                    <?php foreach( $posts as $p ): ?>
                                        <li>
                                            <span><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $p->ID ); ?>">
                                                <?php echo get_the_title( $p->ID ); ?>
                                                </a></span>
                                            <span><?php echo get_field('reference_description', $p->ID); ?></span>
                                            <span class="number"><?php echo get_field('reference_number', $p->ID); ?></span>
                                            <span><?php echo get_field('reference_pdf', $p->ID); ?></span>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </ul>

                                <?php endif; ?>

                          </div>
                          <footer class="w3-container w3-teal">
                            <p>Modal Footer</p>
                          </footer>
                      </div>
                     </div>
                    </div>

                    <p>&nbsp;</p>

            </li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

            </ul>

        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the button click action and the modal's id:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" ...
// Then later,
<div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
```

All buttons have the same onclick handler calling the div with the ID of id01, and all of the modal divs have an ID of id01; so, only the first one is showing. You need to increment the id as you're looping through. Something like (shortened for readability):

```
<?php if( have_rows('api_properties') ): ?>
  <?php $id_increment = 0; ?>
  <ul>
    <?php while ( have_rows('api_properties') ) : the_row(); ?>
      // Your setup
      <button onclick="document.getElementById('id0<?php echo $id_increment; ?>').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Open Modal</button>
      // More markup
      <div id="id0<?php echo $id_increment; ?>" class="w3-modal">
      // Rest of your modal and list markup
      <?php $id_increment++; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Each time it loops through a "row" of the repeater, it will increase the `$id_increment` variable which will change the ID of the modal and the button used to open it.

Comment: Amazing! This works great, Joe! Really appreciate you taking the time to help me out here. I have been racking my brain all weekend. Have a good one!